# Filter dictionary through properties

Tags: c#

I have a dictionary that I would like to pass externally through a property but I would like to limit some features like the clear method.  Here's the code that i've implemented.

```
// dictionary private declaration inside the class
private Dictionary<int, string> _value = new Dictionary<int, string>();

// here's the property declaration for access the dictionary outside the class
public new Dictionary<int, string> Value
{
    get
    {
        return _value;
    }
    set
    {
        // here is where i'd like to avoid some dictionary features like clear() and give only the opportunity to add or change existing values
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

It’s possible through the “set” of this property to limit some of the features of the dictionary? Maybe using a switch or an if statement?

Comment: `Dictionary` implements a few different interfaces, such as `IReadOnlyDictionary` - you could return it as one of those (assuming any of them fulfill your criteria)

Comment: Alternatively, you use the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and return a dictionary wrapper such as the one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9490016/3744182) to [Code Contracts: Ensures Unproven & Requires Unproven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7419134/3744182) and disable the unwanted methods in the wrapper by overriding them and throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

There are a [ReadonlyDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlydictionary-2?view=netframework-4.8) that acts as a wrapper around a dictionary, and a corresponding IReadOnlyDictionary interface.

If you are on .Net core 3 there is also an [ImmutableDictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutabledictionary-2?view=netcore-3.0) if the dictionary never needs to be changed.

If this is to coarse grained, you can always create your own wrapper that works however you want it to.